# How to save captured or image that selected from gallery using image provider, in to assets folder?

Tags: image, flutter, dart, path, save-image

I want to save image that captured from following function into app asset folder.

```
_openGallery(BuildContext context) async{
          var picture = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

          this.setState((){
            imageFile=picture;
          });
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        }

        _openCamera(BuildContext context) async {
          var picture = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
          this.setState((){
            imageFile=picture;
          });
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        }
```

I've tried this code

```
Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String path = directory.path;
File newImage = await _image.copy('$path');
```

but it gives me this error **OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2 flutter**..Can someone help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try giving name to your file

```
Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String path = directory.path+'/my_image.png';
File f = File(path)
f.writeAsBytes(yourImage.asBytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
  Directory pathd = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String path =pathd.path;
  print("$path");
  final File newImage = await imageFile.copy('$path/name.jpg');
```